# will my structure for database in firebase affect the speed of loading?

Tags: ios, database, swift, firebase

I am using firebase as backend for my app. My app will be some sort of expense tracker. The way that I am thinking I should restructure my data so that I can filter the dates easily is as such.

uid/expenses/category/year/month/day/uniquekey/details

to dig into the snapshots would be something like this

```
func retrieveData (){
    _ = dataRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshotOne) in

        if let snapshotTwo = snapshotOne.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            if let snapshotThree = snapshotTwo.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                if let snapshotFour = snapshotThree.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for item in snapshotFour {
                        //retrieve details
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what the consequences are to have to dig so deep into the database and whether my structure for database is okay? could anyone advise?

Comment: The [Firebase documentation recommends against nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data), for various reasons. But looping over the snapshots like that is fine. The `.ChildAdded` loads all data for `snapshotOne`, `snapshotTwo`, `snapshotThree` and `snapshotFour`.

Answer (score 3):

Any Change to Data structure will effect your database.

Firebase prefers Flattened Data 
& Using Indices to Define Complex Relationships:

A lot of times in building apps, it's preferable to download a subset of a list. This is particularly common if the list contains thousands of records or more. When this relationship is static, and one-directional, we can use queries to grab a subset of data, or simply nest the entries under the logical grouping.

```
{
    "messages": {
      "john": {
          "rec1": "Walk the dog",
          "rec2": "Buy milk",
          "rec3": "Win a gold medal in the Olympics"
      }
    }
  }
```

However, we already know that flattening data is a best practice. So let's see why, by examining where this structure begins to break down. If we move into something more dynamic, like shared chat rooms, then suddenly our data (e.g. lists of rooms, lists of messages) now have two-way relationships.
Users can belong to a group and groups comprise a list of users. A first attempt at resolving this data structure would probably look this:

```
    {
    "users": {
      "mchen": { "name": "Mary Chen" },
      "brinchen": { "name": "Byambyn Rinchen" },
      "hmadi": { "name": "Hamadi Madi" }
    },
    "groups": {
      "alpha": {
         "name": "Alpha Tango",
         "members": {
            "m1": "mchen",
            "m2": "brinchen",
            "m3": "hamadi"
         }
      },
      "bravo": { ... },
      "charlie": { ... }
    }
  }
```

You can read more here.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

The whole structure of your database is related to the data you structure to store. 
Also consider reading more about the Security and Rules.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html

Comment: I did read this already. But I dont know how it can apply to me. all the expense posted are only for the user themselves. noone else would be accessing them.

Comment: All you need to consider is To one or To many relationships. 
It will directly help you in speeding up to access a logical group.

Comment: well it is a to one relationship i suppose. because what you upload if what you can see thats all. so in this case my data structure should be fine? even though there are so many nodes because of the details.

Comment: I guess you should study 
Firebase prefers Flattened Data & Using Indices to Define Complex Relationships in the link above.Creating a balance between Flattened Data and defining complexing relationships might help your solution.